# How to use up arrow key in QKeySequence

Tags: python, pyqt5

What is the name for up_arrow in Pyqt5

I have this code and it works fine:

```
QShortcut(QKeySequence('1'), self).activated.connect(function)
```

How do I use the up key instead of '1'

I want something like this:

```
QShortcut(QKeySequence(up_key), self).activated.connect(function)
```

What is the correct syntax for up_key? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It was literally just 'up':

```
QShortcut(QKeySequence('up'), self).activated.connect(function)
```

Comment: or  `QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Up)`